# atmega328pb mcu gets bricked after uploading bootloader

Tags: atmel, bootloader, avrdude, fuse-bits, atmega328pb

i have a strange problem, maybe this post will be long, but i try to give all the details:

i’ve designed a pcb with smd components, around the atmega328pb mcu. it uses an external 16mhz clock and has all the needed decoupling caps, voltage regulator, etc. i’m sure that the design should work, because i already used the same arrangement in other projects.

[image]

i have ordered the parts from tme.eu, the exact model of the mcu is ATMEGA328PB-AN. these are smd parts, so, before programming, you have to solder it in place. i have some experience with atmel mcu, already used several types, like 328, 2560, attiny, etc. for programing i use usbasp device from ali. (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/FREE-SHIPPING-1LOT-New-USBASP-USBISP-AVR-Programmer-USB-ATMEGA8-ATMEGA128-Support-Win7-64K/2003972227.html)

so far, i have used this device without problem. however, with these new chips, i can’t manage to work:

first, i’ve tried the simple arduino ide method, selecting:
tools > arduino nano > atmega328p
tools > programmer > usbasp
tools > burn bootloader

in the first instance, the upload didn’t worked, because of the different chip id (between atmel328p and 328pb). so i edited the c:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\etc\ avrdude.conf file, line 8797, to signature  = 0x1e 0x95 0x16;

this way it apparently uploaded the bootloader, however, the mcu gets bricked, no longer answers to any code uploading attempt nor bootloader uploading attempt (tried with usbasp, another arduino via isp, etc)

so, i’ve desoldered the mcu, and soldered another brand new one. this time i’ve tried the avrdudess v2.8 app. based on this article:
http://www.electronics-lab.com/burning-the-bootloader-on-atmega328-using-usbasp-programmer/

here the app detected the usbasp, detected the correct mcu model. i have done everything exactly as in the article, double checked everything. hitted the program! button, and got this output. as you can see, it apparently failed to write the extended fuse correctly, and probably this is bricking the mcu. i’ve checked with the fuse bit calculator, and for the extended fuse 0xf5 is not an option…

now it no longer can read the fuse bits, no longer can program the mcu, nothing works  bricked 2 mcu so far.
just to be sure, i’ve checked the 16mhz clock signal with a scope, it works, got the nice sine wave.

also, desoldered a working mcu from an arduino nano, and soldered into my pcb, it works ok, i can upload sketch via the usbasp.

```
Checking for updates…
You have the latest version 
Detected 1e9516 = ATmega328PB
Reading fuses…
SUCCESS: Read low fuse
SUCCESS: Read high fuse
SUCCESS: Read extended fuse
Reading lock bits…
SUCCESS: Read lock bits
optiboot_atmega328.hex: 502 / 32,768 Bytes (1.53%)
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

avrdude.exe: set SCK frequency to 1500000 Hz
avrdude.exe: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude.exe: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x1e9516 (probably m328pb)
avrdude.exe: NOTE: “flash” memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude.exe: erasing chip
avrdude.exe: set SCK frequency to 1500000 Hz
avrdude.exe: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude.exe: reading input file “C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot\optiboot_atmega328.hex”
avrdude.exe: input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot\optiboot_atmega328.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude.exe: writing flash (32768 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude.exe: 32768 bytes of flash written
avrdude.exe: verifying flash memory against C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot\optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude.exe: load data flash data from input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot\optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude.exe: input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot\optiboot_atmega328.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude.exe: input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot\optiboot_atmega328.hex contains 32768 bytes
avrdude.exe: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% -0.00s

avrdude.exe: verifying …
avrdude.exe: 32768 bytes of flash verified
avrdude.exe: reading input file “0xFF”
avrdude.exe: writing lfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude.exe: 1 bytes of lfuse written
avrdude.exe: verifying lfuse memory against 0xFF:
avrdude.exe: load data lfuse data from input file 0xFF:
avrdude.exe: input file 0xFF contains 1 bytes
avrdude.exe: reading on-chip lfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude.exe: verifying …
avrdude.exe: 1 bytes of lfuse verified
avrdude.exe: reading input file “0xDE”
avrdude.exe: writing hfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude.exe: 1 bytes of hfuse written
avrdude.exe: verifying hfuse memory against 0xDE:
avrdude.exe: load data hfuse data from input file 0xDE:
avrdude.exe: input file 0xDE contains 1 bytes
avrdude.exe: reading on-chip hfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude.exe: verifying …
avrdude.exe: 1 bytes of hfuse verified
avrdude.exe: reading input file “0x05”
avrdude.exe: writing efuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ***failed;
################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude.exe: 1 bytes of efuse written
avrdude.exe: verifying efuse memory against 0x05:
avrdude.exe: load data efuse data from input file 0x05:
avrdude.exe: input file 0x05 contains 1 bytes
avrdude.exe: reading on-chip efuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude.exe: verifying …
avrdude.exe: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
0xf5 != 0x05
avrdude.exe: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude.exe done. Thank you.

Reading fuses…
WARNING: Unable to read fuses/lock bits

avrdude.exe: set SCK frequency to 1500000 Hz
avrdude.exe: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude.exe: error: program enable: target doesn’t answer. 1
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
this check.

avrdude.exe done. Thank you.

Reading fuses…
WARNING: Unable to read fuses/lock bits

avrdude.exe: set SCK frequency to 1500000 Hz
avrdude.exe: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude.exe: error: program enable: target doesn’t answer. 1
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
this check.

avrdude.exe done. Thank you.
```

best regards,
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see table 32-5, page 386 of the [ATmega328PB datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001906C.pdf).

The efuse has the upper 4 bits always set. So it **must** read 0xF…. 0x0… is an invalid setting which cannot be verified as correct.  Which results in a wrong programming.

The default setting is 0xF7, try that.

---

I also find your crystal circuit dubious. What purpose do R26 and R27 serve?

Please build the crystal circuit as recommended in the [AVR186 app note](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8128-Best-Practices-for-the-PCB-Layout-of-Oscillators_ApplicationNote_AVR186.pdf).

Comment: thanks for the answer! the r26 is a 2M resistor, it appears also in the original arduino uno schematic: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf, and r27 is a 27R resistor, i've read somewhere that they can be used for protecting the cristal... but i can easily remove them, if you think they are not needed.

Comment: You don't need those resistors. The 27Ω resistor would be needed if you used certain crystals which want to be driven with low power, and the µC had no internal provisions for that. But this AVR has, it's a low power oscillator already.

Comment: removed both resistors, shorted r27, and now IT WORKS!!! i'm very happy :))) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What you show in your schematic is a crystal, not an external oscillator.

Although you stated that the clock is present one of the most common causes for "bricking an AVR" is configuring for an external oscillator when you actually are using a crystal. As Janka mentions the AVR does not require (or want) bias or drive limiting resistors on the crystal.

If you do accidentally "brick" a device it can be recovered by providing an external clock to XTAL1 as described in the datasheet (it is ambiguous as to which pin is the EXTCLK). If you do not have a signal generator or external clock you can derive one from another Arduino.

See for example: [Recovering a bricked AVR](https://classbproject.com/recovering-a-bricked-avr/)

Comment: i see. thanks for both of you clarifying this. will remove now the resistors, and check if it works. btw, the crystal i've used is this one: https://www.tme.eu/Document/f31bf43b0a0e721846cb7be7a5f5a9f3/abm8.pdf